# Can I add item to Google Docs right-click menu for my Add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-docs-api

I'm writing an add-on for Google Docs, using Google Apps Script and I see that I can add actions to the Add-ons menu using DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu().addItem. My current action launches a sidebar. But that's several clicks away from the user. I'd like to put an option on the right click menu and / or make the action available via a hotkey.

Is there a way to add to the right click menu or create a hot key to launch my add-on item?

Comment: You can add a pull-down menu item that appears after the Help pull-down. Would that work for you?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried adding a custom top-level menu and it is better than having it be on the add-on menu, but I'd rather make it even easier by putting it in the right click or assigning a hotkey to launch. Any way to do those?

Comment: Definitely not a hot-key, nor can you set menu hot keys with an under-bar off a custom menu (like Alt-F to open the File menu).  I do not think a right click can be added either.

Comment: There is a pending feature request on [Need a support to map shortcut to script functions](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=306), you may want to follow this ticket to be updated. As @Cooper said you can trigger it `onOpen` and use a [Custom sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) that display a [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) user interface inside a Google Docs, Forms, or Sheets editor. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could just launch your sidebar in the onOpen event for the spreadsheet and it will be there right from the start.